# Pseudo-terminal not printing output

Tags: c, gcc, pty

So here is my code which is designed to open an additional gnome terminal and print the first 20 Fibonacci numbers in the newly opened terminal console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "apue.h"

int Fibonacci(unsigned int n);

int main() {
    char cmd[256];
    char str[40][256];
    char *name = tempnam(NULL, NULL);
    char *line = "\n";
    FILE *log;

    mkfifo(name, 0777);
    log = fopen(name, "w+");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         sprintf(str[(2 * i)], "%s",line);
         fputs(str[(2 * i)], log);
         sprintf(str[(2 * i) + 1], "%u\n", Fibonacci(i));
         fputs(str[(2 * i) + 1], log);
         fflush(NULL);
    }
    if (fork() == 0) {
        sprintf(cmd, "gnome-terminal -e cat %s", name);
        system(cmd);       
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 40 ; j++) {    
            fgets(str[j], sizeof(cmd), log);            
        }
        exit(0);
    } else
    if (fork() < 0) {
        perror("fork () error");    
    }
}

int Fibonacci(unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else
    if (n > 1) {
        return Fibonacci(n - 2) + Fibonacci(n - 1);
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following warning message:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/" -*-
Compilation started at Sun Sep  3 15:46:28

gcc  -o FIB0   Fibonacci.c
/tmp/ccobnJV9.o: In function `main':
Fibonacci.c:(.text+0x231f): warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'

Compilation finished at Sun Sep  3 15:46:28
```

When I execute it from the gnome terminal command line, the new terminal pops open but with **no output!** How could I fix this code to make it work?

When I use

```
 sprintf(cmd, "xterm -e cat %s", name);
```

instead of "gnome-terminal", it works correctly. So how does one communicate between gnome terminals using GCC?

Comment: It won't have anything to do with using tempnam.

Comment: @immibis: Good point. It works when I substitute "gnome-terminal" for "xterm" in the sprintf() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sprintf(cmd, "gnome-terminal -e \"cat %s\"", name);
```

gnone-terminal's man request a string after -e.

Comment: Works **PERFECTLY** now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra problem in your forking mechanism:

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    /* do something in the child */
} else
if (fork() < 0) {   //<--- fork AGAIN!
    perror("fork () error");    
}
```

The parent process is forked twice!

You should instead store the pid:

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    /* do something in the child */
} else
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork () error");    
}
```

Comment: When I implement your changes by calling fork() once, the first thing that happens is the main terminal prints "fork() error: success", and after almost a 1 second delay the output shows up in the new terminal. Whereas the original code produces no such error msgs and the new terminal pops up right away with the desired output. Hmmm......

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a command line.

If I run

```
echo hi > ~/temp
gnome-terminal -e cat ~/temp
```

then I get a terminal running `cat` (which is initially blank, until I type something and press enter)

If I run

```
xterm -e cat ~/temp
```

then I get an xterm that pops up, prints "hi" and closes very quickly.

So it appears `gnome-terminal -e cat /some/path` is not running `cat /some/path` but only `cat`.

If you want to run `cat /some/path` in a gnome-terminal then you have to use the command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "cat /some/path"
```

Notice the extra quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

Either use quotations, as immibis suggested, or use `-x` instead of `-e`. See manpage of `gnome-terminal` for the details.